# What is the equivalent of TiXmlAttribute for tinyxml2 and how to use it?

Tags: c++, tinyxml, tinyxml2

I've encountered a problem that I'm not being able to solve using tinyxml2.

I have a function that receives as a parameter a `XMLElement` and I need to iterate over its attributes. With tinyxml, this worked:

```
void xmlreadLight(TiXmlElement* light){
    for (TiXmlAttribute* a = light->FirstAttribute(); a ; a = a->Next()) {
         //Do stuff
    }
}
```

Using the same with tinyxml2, like in the example below, I get the following error:

> a value of type `const tinyxml2::XMLAttribute *` cannot be used to initialize an entity of type `tinyxml2::XMLAttribute *`

```
void xmlreadLight(XMLElement* light){
    for (XMLAttribute* a = light->FirstAttribute(); a ; a = a->Next()) {
         //Do stuff
    }
}
```

The XML code in question is:

```
<lights>
   <light type="POINT" posX=-1.0 posY=1.0 posZ=-1.0 ambtR=1.0 ambtG=1.0 ambtB=1.0 />
</lights>
```

where light is the `XMLElement` passed into the function `xmlreadLight`. Not sure if my question is properly set up, so if theres some info missing, let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going by the error message, it looks like you need to do:

```
for (const XMLAttribute* a = light->FirstAttribute(); a ; a = a->Next()) { ...
     ^^^^^
```

Presumbably, the return type of `FirstAttribute` has been made `const` in tinyxml2.

---

If you check the Github repository for the [`tinyxml2.h`](https://github.com/leethomason/tinyxml2/blob/master/tinyxml2.h) file on line 1513 you will see this:

```
/// Return the first attribute in the list.
const XMLAttribute* FirstAttribute() const {
    return _rootAttribute;
}
```

Comment: I tried that but it seems that I was missing some debug information. I assumed the application wasn't running because of that, even with the const, but there was another error along the code. Thanks though, that was the solution I needed.